# variable for shipping tracking no in email

Tags: shipment-tracking

I want to add the tracking no to an email, just the number not url.

what is the tracking # variable ?

**update**

I have modifed the code in track.phtml to this

```
?>
<?php $_shipment=$this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order=$this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order && $_shipment->getAllTracks()): ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but I don't want to have all tracking #, I only want the last added one

how can I do that ?

Comment: What Magento version?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Are you calling track.phtml in your email template?

Comment: no, it is new empty template I just want to add

Comment: tracking # XXXXXXXX   where XXXXXXXX is the tracking number for the the order

Answer (score 1):

You should include the tracking details using the following code:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' 
shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: this will show complete table with    Shipped By Tracking Number and its value. however I only want the value of the tracking #

Comment: Duplicate the file and strip out what you don't want

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: I have modified it to this

Comment: ?>
<?php $_shipment=$this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order=$this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order && $_shipment->getAllTracks()): ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: however, I don't want to get all tracks, only the last one, how can I do that ?

Comment: You have multiple tracking numbers?

Comment: for some orders yes

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to just get the last track aswell, so i modified the track.phtml to this:

```
<?php
$_shipment=$this->getShipment();
$_order=$this->getOrder();
if ($_shipment && $_order && $_shipment->getAllTracks()):
$i=0;
$tracks = array();
foreach($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): 
    $i++;
    $tracks[] = $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber());
endforeach;

echo $tracks[count($tracks)-1];
endif;
?>
```

Then I just include the Track-id in the email with:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```